# Excluding multiple patterns with one grep command

Tags: grep

I was wondering if there is a best way to run the following command

```
cat cisco.log-20151103.log | grep -v "90.192.142.138" | grep -v "PIX" | grep -v "Intrusion"
```

I tried

```
cat cisco.log-20151103.log | grep -v "90.192.142.138|PIX|Intrusion"
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

two other options

```
grep -v -e 90.192.142.138 -e PIX -e Intrusion cisco.log-20151103.log
```

and assuming fixed strings

```
grep -vF '90.192.142.138
PIX
Intrusion
' cisco.log-20151103.log
```

Answer (score 10):

grep does not necessarily need input from a pipe, so you could do

```
grep -vE '90\.192\.142\.138|PIX|Intrusion' cisco.log-20151103.log
```

Capital E switches on regular expression mode and dots need to be escaped in this case.

Comment: That should be `-E` turns on _Extended_ regular expression mode, which allows the alternation `|` of patterns.  `grep` without -E has regular expressions and dots are meaningful.  The dots should have been escaped in the question, but it's unlikely that the sequence of numbers would match anything else anyway. `grep -f` turns off regular expressions.

Comment: The dots should be escaped in any case; the example given (in OP and answer) would match `190.192.142.138`; so ideally the IP address piece should be anchored if possible, or include whatever delimiter is before the IP address in the log, supposing a comma "," to make things clear: `grep -vE ',90\.192\.142\.138,|PIX|Intrusion' cisco.log-20151103.log`

Answer (score 2):

`grep -vE "90.192.142.138|PIX|Intrusion" cisco.log-20151103.log`

Comment: Since the `.` matches any character this also matches e.g. `90C192X142R138` and that is not what the OP asked. You should escape special (regex) characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -v -f exclude.list
$ cat exclude.list
90.192.142.138
PIX
Intrusion
```

Comment: This works fine, I'm not sure why someone downvoted it.

Comment: this requires another command which is a creation of exclude.list